# add days to current date in javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, date, formulas

I am currently using this formula to populate the current date into a fillable PDF for work:

```
var f = this.getField("Today"); 
f.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", new Date());
```

This fillable PDF is a government document and once it's printed expires in 45 days including the date printed. Like a Temp Tag for a vehicle.

How do I add 44 days to this formula so that it automatically kicks out 45 days down the road?

Comment: Are you against using additional libraries? Moment.js has all the date functions that you could ever need.

Comment: var todayDate = new Date();
    todayDate.setDate(todayDate.getDate() + 44);

Comment: There are a [*huge number of duplicates*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%5Bdate%5D+add+days+to+date).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you wanna do:

```
var laterDate = new Date(); // create new Date object set to current date
laterDate.setDate(laterDate.getDate() + 44); // add 44 days
```

then you could use your util library and display it:

```
util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", laterDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

For handling dates in JavaScript, you could use **[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/)**. With moment you can perform a wide range of operations on dates and time. Check it's docs for more info. As for your query, you could do

```
    moment().add(44, 'days');
```

Comment: Answers should not rely on a library that the OP hasn't mentioned or tagged.

Comment: Sorry, I will keep that in mind. Since it was mentioned before edit that it could use any method, so I suggested that.